# TableView - signal SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to create a TableView and put in data from a NSArray. However, I am getting this error:

```
2012-12-21 15:53:10.239 Arr[13219:c07] -[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71ccb60
2012-12-21 15:53:10.240 Arr[13219:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71ccb60'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c90012 0x10cde7e 0x1d1b4bd 0x1c7fbbc 0x1c7f94e 0x1f96e8 0x1fc3c4 0xc0fa2 0xc092c 0xc4426 0xc90ce 0x6592d 0x10e16b0 0x228cfc0 0x228133c 0x228ceaf 0x1048cd 0x4d1a6 0x4bcbf 0x4bbd9 0x4ae34 0x4ac6e 0x4ba29 0x4e922 0xf8fec 0x45bc4 0x45dbf 0x45f55 0x4ef67 0x12fcc 0x13fab 0x25315 0x2624b 0x17cf8 0x1bebdf9 0x1bebad0 0x1c05bf5 0x1c05962 0x1c36bb6 0x1c35f44 0x1c35e1b 0x137da 0x1565c 0x1c2d 0x1b55 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I am not really sure what code is causing this, so I'll just attach the two table methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Creation of the NSArray:

```
@implementation ArrViewController {
    NSArray *tableData;
}

@synthesize itemTxt = _itemTxt;
@synthesize itemsLabel = _itemsLabel;
@synthesize model = _model;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
}
```

Comment: do you have `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView `method in your code?

Comment: No I don't, but according to [AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/), it works without it

Comment: Yes if it is not a grouped tableview you may not need it otherwise `return integer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have improperly set the data source for your table view. This makes the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` message to be sent to the wrong object, a `UIView` as it appears from the error message:

```
 [UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]
```

Review/post the code where you set the `dataSource` property of your `UITableView` to find out what is wrong. You are likely passing in the wrong object.

The data source is the very object in whose class you define `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` as per your post.

Comment: I just used the graphical UI builder to CTRL-Drag the TableView to the  ViewController. I've added the NSArray object to the thread

Comment: where are you defining `tableView numberOfRowsInSection`? that is the class to be instantiated as a data source... can you show what you do with SimpleTableController and how do you instantiate the table view?

Answer (score 0):

in Your .h file Use the Following Code

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *your_Table;
```

in Your .m file

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize your_Table;
```

in `Xib` File Connect The `Delegate` and `dataSource` to `Fileowner`.

or in `ViewDidLoad` Assign it programmatically

```
your_Table.delegate=self;
your_table.dataSuorce=self;
```

After That use this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableData count];
}
```

Hope it will Help you.

If not, Then post your Code from .h file.